# sqllite error when running airflow scheduler on mac

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I keep getting the error below when running airflow? any ideas? This happens as soon as i kick off the airflow scheduler. It was previously working but seems to have stopped when i updated my mac.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: job
```

and then the following traceback

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 1221, in scheduler
    job.run()
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/base_job.py", line 212, in run
    session.commit()
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1036, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 503, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 482, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2496, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2637, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2597, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    uow,
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1136, in _emit_insert_statements
    statement, params
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 984, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1103, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1288, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1482, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: job
[SQL: INSERT INTO job (dag_id, state, job_type, start_date, end_date, latest_heartbeat, executor_class, hostname, unixname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (None, 'running', 'SchedulerJob', '2020-12-10 23:11:18.838822', None, '2020-12-10 23:11:18.838839', 'SequentialExecutor', 'ip-192-168-0-53.us-west-2.compute.internal', 'user1')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I have tried to downgrade to an older version of sqlalchemy but still the same issues. i am currently using Version: 1.3.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this :
$ airflow initdb

Also check if Airflow Home is Set or not .
If initdb doesn't work :
Try with airflow resetdb, But before that if you have any data take backup of your DAGS folder from the Airflow home directory.

Comment: Thanks i needed to unset my airflow home directory and reset.